# How to synchronize between threadgroups in Metal

Tags: ios, metal

I want to synchronize writes to a `MTLBuffer` between threadgroups in Metal kernel. I've tried to use the `atomic_uint` type and `atomic_fetch_add_explicit` function. This should work, but my problem is that I don't know how to interpret the values on the CPU side. I would prefer a locking mechanism that I could use to synchronize writes to the same buffer from different threadgroups. Is there such mechanism or some other workaround that is not bound to atomic types?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say you're having trouble interpreting the values on the CPU side. If you have a buffer of `uint`s, then it's just a buffer of `uint32_t` values (if using Obj-C++ or similar).  I would suggest you avoid locking mechanisms if at all possible, because they are tricky on GPUs and may perform very badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm facing similar problems in 16-bit float conversion.

You could try to interpret values on the CPU side by extracting raw bits from the buffer, comparing with the internal format of the atomic_uint, and then try to use the information obtained to recast as the datatype you need. A low-level approach for sure, but works when nothing else will.

Answer (score 1):

Locking generally doesn't work because not all thread groups are necessarily alive concurrently. If you try to implement a spin lock, for example, you may just livelock because the producer of your data may not have launched yet, assuming everything is the same kernel. Another problem with locking schemes is you can't cause the GPU to block or context switch, so you'll just be wasting power spinning, potentially forever, waiting for the resource to become available.

Prefer instead using global atomics for operations that are what atomic ops are traditionally used for. For example, if you want to write a simple malloc() that suballocates from a preallocated MTLBuffer, you can use a global atomic to increment the offset into the MTLBuffer by the size of each allocation. Return the old offset+MTLBuffer base address as the start of the allocation.